# Google Analytics Api: How to use Custom Variables in the code?

Tags: google-analytics, google-analytics-api, google-analytics-firebase

Trying to emulate how I do it on the Google Analytics Dashboard.[image]

How a Segment can be created with a `Custom Variable Value`? I have tried writing following code but it does not return any result back.
Can `Custom Variable Value` set as a `DimensionFilter`?

```
// Create Dimension Filter.
          SegmentDimensionFilter dimensionFilter = new SegmentDimensionFilter()
              .setDimensionName("ga:customVarValue1")
              .setOperator("EXACT")
              .setExpressions(Arrays.asList("account_id"));


          // Create Segment Filter Clause.
          SegmentFilterClause segmentFilterClause = new SegmentFilterClause()
              .setDimensionFilter(dimensionFilter);

          // Create the Or Filters for Segment.
          OrFiltersForSegment orFiltersForSegment = new OrFiltersForSegment()
              .setSegmentFilterClauses(Arrays.asList(segmentFilterClause));

          // Create the Simple Segment.
          SimpleSegment simpleSegment = new SimpleSegment()
              .setOrFiltersForSegment(Arrays.asList(orFiltersForSegment));

          // Create the Segment Filters.
          SegmentFilter segmentFilter = new SegmentFilter()
              .setSimpleSegment(simpleSegment);

          // Create the Segment Definition.
          SegmentDefinition segmentDefinition = new SegmentDefinition()
              .setSegmentFilters(Arrays.asList(segmentFilter));

          // Create the Dynamic Segment.
          DynamicSegment dynamicSegment = new DynamicSegment()
              .setSessionSegment(segmentDefinition)
              .setName("Sessions with Safari browser");

          // Create the Segments object.
          Segment segment = new Segment()
              .setDynamicSegment(dynamicSegment);

          // Create the ReportRequest object.
          ReportRequest request = new ReportRequest()
              .setViewId(VIEW_ID)
              .setDateRanges(Arrays.asList(dateRange))
              .setDimensions(Arrays.asList(segmentDimensions))
              .setSegments(Arrays.asList(segment))
              .setMetrics(Arrays.asList(sessions));
```

Comment: There is a difference between the API call and the segment in the UI. In the API you are looking for an **exact match** but in the API you are looking if the string **contains** `account_id`. So if the no sessions contain contain the exact value `account_id` nothing should show up in the results.

Comment: @Matt Thanks for your comment. I changed `contains` to `exactly matches` in UI and got the same result back. But API call doesn't return any result back. What do you think about the code? Is there any other way to use ga:customVarValue1 with an id?

Comment: @Matt Is there any other way to get the data for a `Custom Variable` without creating a `Segment`?

Comment: It is my understanding that a custom var should behave just like any other dimension. You shouldn't need a segment. If you wanted to filter results you could simply use a filter. I'd suggest playing around with the [query explorer](https://ga-dev-tools.appspot.com/query-explorer/?start-date=2014-07-21&end-date=2014-07-21&metrics=ga%3Asessions&dimensions=ga%3AcustomVarName1&samplingLevel=HIGHER_PRECISION&start-index=1&max-results=100) to see if you can get the data you need.

Comment: @Matt You are right! It worked for me. I set a dimension as `ga:customVarValue1` then added a dimension filter with an account_id. It returned some result back to me. Now I can play around with it and get the data I want.

Comment: @Matt I will take that. Adding a dimension as `ga:customVarValue1` returned a couple of ids for me but those ids do not belong to our database. Earlier I got confused with it and thought those were account ids.

Comment: @Matt I am back to square one now! Can you please help me with it?

Comment: A few suggestions to start:
1. Move away from custom variables as they were replaced with [custom dimensions](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/2709828) for [Universal Analytics](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/2790010). 
2. Use the [API explorer](https://developers.google.com/apis-explorer/#search/batchget/m/analyticsreporting/v4/analyticsreporting.reports.batchGet) to build and share your request for debugging.
3. Initially query without a filter or a segment to ensure the data you are looking for is present in the View you are querying.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A few things to help you in the long run.

1. Move away from custom variables as they were replaced with [custom dimensions](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/2709828) for [Universal Analytics](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/2790010).
2. Use the [API explorer](https://developers.google.com/apis-explorer/#search/batchget/m/analyticsreporting/v4/analyticsreporting.reports.batchGet?_h=3&resource=%257B%250A++%2522reportRequests%2522%253A%250A++%255B%250A++++%257B%250A++++++%2522viewId%2522%253A+%25221174%2522%252C%250A++++++%2522dateRanges%2522%253A+%255B%250A++++++++%257B%2522endDate%2522%253A+%25222014-11-30%2522%252C+%2522startDate%2522%253A+%25222014-11-01%2522%257D%250A++++++%255D%252C%250A++++++%2522metrics%2522%253A+%255B%250A++++++++%257B%2522expression%2522%253A+%2522ga%253Apageviews%2522%257D%252C%250A++++++++%257B%2522expression%2522%253A+%2522ga%253Asessions%2522%257D%250A++++++%255D%252C%250A++++++%2522dimensions%2522%253A+%255B%257B%2522name%2522%253A+%2522ga%253AcustomVarValue1%2522%257D%252C+%257B%2522name%2522%253A+%2522ga%253Acountry%2522%257D%255D%252C%250A++++++%2522dimensionFilterClauses%2522%253A+%255B%250A++++++++%257B%250A++++++++++%2522filters%2522%253A+%255B%250A++++++++++++%257B%250A++++++++++++++%2522dimensionName%2522%253A+%2522ga%253AcustomVarValue1%2522%252C%250A++++++++++++++%2522operator%2522%253A+%2522EXACT%2522%252C%250A++++++++++++++%2522expressions%2522%253A+%255B%2522account_id%2522%255D%250A++++++++++++%257D%250A++++++++++%255D%250A++++++++%257D%250A++++++%255D%250A++++%257D%250A++%255D%250A%257D&) to build and share your request for debugging.
3. Initially query without a filter or a segment to ensure the data you are looking for is present in the View you are querying.

With that said to create a request with a segment on a custom variable:

#### Java Example

```
  // Create the DateRange object.
  DateRange dateRange = new DateRange();
  dateRange.setStartDate("2015-06-15");
  dateRange.setEndDate("2015-06-30");

  // Create the Metrics object.
  Metric sessions = new Metric()
      .setExpression("ga:sessions")
      .setAlias("sessions");

  //Create the custom var  dimension.
  Dimension customVarValue1 = new Dimension()
      .setName("ga:customVarValue1");

  // Create the segment dimension.
  Dimension segmentDimensions = new Dimension()
      .setName("ga:customVarValue1");

  // Create Dimension Filter.
  SegmentDimensionFilter dimensionFilter = new SegmentDimensionFilter()
      .setDimensionName("ga:customVarValue1")
      .setOperator("PARTIAL")
      .setExpressions(Arrays.asList("account_id"));

  // Create Segment Filter Clause.
  SegmentFilterClause segmentFilterClause = new SegmentFilterClause()
      .setDimensionFilter(dimensionFilter);

  // Create the Or Filters for Segment.
  OrFiltersForSegment orFiltersForSegment = new OrFiltersForSegment()
      .setSegmentFilterClauses(Arrays.asList(segmentFilterClause));

  // Create the Simple Segment.
  SimpleSegment simpleSegment = new SimpleSegment()
      .setOrFiltersForSegment(Arrays.asList(orFiltersForSegment));

  // Create the Segment Filters.
  SegmentFilter segmentFilter = new SegmentFilter()
      .setSimpleSegment(simpleSegment);

  // Create the Segment Definition.
  SegmentDefinition segmentDefinition = new SegmentDefinition()
      .setSegmentFilters(Arrays.asList(segmentFilter));

  // Create the Dynamic Segment.
  DynamicSegment dynamicSegment = new DynamicSegment()
      .setSessionSegment(segmentDefinition)
      .setName("Sessions with Safari browser");

  // Create the Segments object.
  Segment segment = new Segment()
      .setDynamicSegment(dynamicSegment);

  // Create the ReportRequest object.
  ReportRequest request = new ReportRequest()
      .setViewId("XXXX")
      .setDateRanges(Arrays.asList(dateRange))
      .setDimensions(Arrays.asList(customVarValue1, segmentDimensions))
      .setSegments(Arrays.asList(segment))
      .setMetrics(Arrays.asList(sessions));

  // Create the GetReportsRequest object.
  GetReportsRequest getReport = new GetReportsRequest()
      .setReportRequests(Arrays.asList(request));

  // Call the batchGet method.
  GetReportsResponse response = analyticsreporting.reports().batchGet(getReport)
      .execute();
```

Things to check.:

1. Ensure that you are using the correct custom variable. Did you mean to search for `ga:customVarName1`?
2. Query for the variable without the segment or filter to ensure the data is present before filtering/segmenting.
3. Ensure that you are using the right [operator](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/v4/rest/v4/reports/batchGet#operator).

Finally if you create a segment in the UI you can always query by segment ID in the API:

#### Java request by segment ID.

```
  // Create the Segments object for returning users.
  Segment segment = new Segment()
      .setSegmentId("gaid::-3");

  // Create the ReportRequest object.
  ReportRequest request = new ReportRequest()
      .setViewId("XXXX")
      .setDateRanges(Arrays.asList(dateRange))
      .setDimensions(Arrays.asList(browser, segmentDimensions))
      .setSegments(Arrays.asList(segment))
      .setMetrics(Arrays.asList(sessions));

  // Create the GetReportsRequest object.
  GetReportsRequest getReport = new GetReportsRequest()
      .setReportRequests(Arrays.asList(request));
```

To get the segment id you can call the [segments.list](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/config/mgmt/v3/mgmtReference/management/segments/list) method in the Analytics Management API.