# How to set a segment filter on Google Analytics Reporting API v4

Tags: php, google-analytics, google-analytics-api, google-analytics-firebase

I am trying to add a segment filter when returning data from Google Analytics Core Reporting API and have the following code:

```
<?php

function getReport($analytics)
{
    $VIEW_ID = "XXX";

    // Create the DateRange object.
    $dateRange = new Google_Service_AnalyticsReporting_DateRange();
    $dateRange->setStartDate("30daysAgo");
    $dateRange->setEndDate("yesterday");

    // Create the Metrics object.
    $sessions = new Google_Service_AnalyticsReporting_Metric();
    $sessions->setExpression("ga:sessions");
    $sessions->setAlias("sessions");

    $goalCompletionAll = new Google_Service_AnalyticsReporting_Metric();
    $goalCompletionAll->setExpression("ga:goalCompletionsAll");
    $goalCompletionAll->setAlias("goalCompletionsAll");

    // Create first dimension object
    $dimensionChannel = new Google_Service_AnalyticsReporting_Dimension();
    $dimensionChannel->setName('ga:channelGrouping');

    // Create second dimension object
    $dimensionSource = new Google_Service_AnalyticsReporting_Dimension();
    $dimensionSource->setName('ga:source');

    // Create Segment object
    $segments = new Google_Service_AnalyticsReporting_Segment();
    $segments->setSegmentId('gaid::-4');

    // Create the ordering object
    $ordering = new Google_Service_AnalyticsReporting_OrderBy();
    $ordering->setFieldName("ga:sessions");
    $ordering->setOrderType("VALUE");
    $ordering->setSortOrder("DESCENDING");

    // Create the Report Request object
    $request = new Google_Service_AnalyticsReporting_ReportRequest();
    $request->setViewId($VIEW_ID);
    $request->setDateRanges($dateRange);

    // Set the metric
    $request->setMetrics([
            $sessions,
            $goalCompletionAll,
    ]);

    // Set the dimension
    $request->setDimensions([
        $dimensionChannel, 
        $dimensionSource
    ]);


    // Set the segments
    $request->setSegments($segments);

    // Set ordering
    $request->setOrderBys($ordering);

    $body = new Google_Service_AnalyticsReporting_GetReportsRequest();
    $body->setReportRequests(array($request));

    return $analytics->reports->batchGet($body);
}
```

But when I run this code I get the following error:

```
Requests with segments must have ga:segment dimension.
```

I followed the example I found was [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37731730/2165516) in Java (the segment Id part). I have got segment ID's setup so, what would I need to do to send in the request for ga:segement dimension?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must create a segment dimension :

```
        $dimensionSegment= new Google_Service_AnalyticsReporting_Dimension();
        $dimensionSegment->setName("ga:segment");
```

And add it to your request :

```
$request->setDimensions([
    $dimensionChannel, 
    $dimensionSource, 
    $dimensionSegment
]);
```

Answer (score 3):

I'm using PHP. My answer is almost the same as the one above, but the syntax `segmentDimensions` worked instead of `dimensionSegment`.

This is what worked for me:

```
// Create the segment dimension.
$segmentDimensions = new Google_Service_AnalyticsReporting_Dimension();
$segmentDimensions->setName("ga:segment");

//create the Segment object.
$segments = new Google_Service_AnalyticsReporting_Segment();
$segments->setSegmentId("gaid::abcDE4fgHIJOOkLm1-nO1p");
```

Then in the Report Request object:

```
$request->setDimensions(array($dimensions, $segmentDimensions));
$request->setSegments(array($segments));
```